# Why does a generator that was working in nightly Rust 1.29 give an error in nightly 1.34.0?

Tags: rust, generator

I am using a Rust generator and it was working fine with nightly 1.29.0:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::{Generator, GeneratorState};

fn main() {
    let mut generator: Box<dyn Generator<Yield = u64, Return = &str>> = Box::new(move || {
        yield 1;
        return "foo";
    });

    unsafe {
        match generator.resume() {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(1) => {
                println!("Yielded");
            }
            _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
        }
        match generator.resume() {
            GeneratorState::Complete("foo") => {
                println!("Completed");
            }
            _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
        }
    }
}
```

However, nightly version 1.34.0 requires the `Generator` to be wrapped in `Pin`, but when I wrap `Generator` into `Pin`, the code doesn't work anymore.

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::{Generator, GeneratorState};
use std::pin::Pin;

fn main() {
    let mut generator: Box<dyn Generator<Yield = u64, Return = &str>> = Box::new(move || {
        yield 1;
        return "foo";
    });

    match Pin::new(&mut generator).resume() {
        GeneratorState::Yielded(1) => {
            println!("Yielded");
        }
        _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
    }
    match Pin::new(&mut generator).resume() {
        GeneratorState::Complete("foo") => {
            println!("Completed");
        }
        _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
    }
}
```

And the code gives the following error.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `resume` found for type `std::pin::Pin<&mut std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Generator<Yield = u64, Return = &str>>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:36
   |
12 |     match Pin::new(&mut generator).resume() {
   |                                    ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `resume` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Generator<Yield = u64, Return = &str>> : std::ops::Generator`
```

When I remove the type of the generator, it works fine:

```
let mut generator = Box::new(move || {
        yield 1;
        return "foo"
});
```

I have a few questions:

- Why does wrapping the `Generator` in `Pin` give the error in the latest version?
- What's the use of using the `Pin` for the generator (as it prevents the value of a pointer from being moved), I don't understand the relation between `Pin` and `Generator`?
- Why does the code work when we remove the type for `generator` variable?
- Why is the `resume` method no longer `unsafe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does generator code that was working in nightly Rust 1.29 give an error in Nightly 1.34.0?

Because this is a *nightly*, *unstable* feature which may change at any time and it changed.

See also:

- [What is the stabilization process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49673121/155423)

> Why does wrapping the `Generator` in `Pin` give the error in the latest version?

As the error message states, `Box<dyn Generator<Yield = u64, Return = &str>>` doesn't implement `Generator`.

See also:

- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)

> What's the use of using the `Pin` for the generator?
>
> Why is the `resume` method no longer unsafe?

The `resume` method was unsafe because you could introduce memory unsafety if the generator had a self-referential variable and it was moved between two calls to `resume`. `Pin` prevents the move, thus removing the unsafety. This is a classic example of wrapping unsafe logic in an API that only exposes a safe interface.

See also:

- [What are the use cases of the newly proposed Pin type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49913846/155423)
- [How to use the Pin struct with self-referential structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49860149/155423)

> Why does the code work when we remove the type for generator variable?

Because it's no longer a trait object (`Box<dyn Generator>`) but just a boxed concrete generator.

See also:

- [Lazy sequence generation in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279122/155423)

---

I'd write this as

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

use std::ops::{Generator, GeneratorState};

fn main() {
    let mut generator = Box::pin(move || {
        yield 1;
        "foo"
    });

    match generator.as_mut().resume() {
        GeneratorState::Yielded(1) => println!("Yielded"),
        _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
    }
    match generator.as_mut().resume() {
        GeneratorState::Complete("foo") => println!("Completed"),
        _ => panic!("unexpected return from resume"),
    }
}
```